# php storm ftp автоматическая отправка измененного файла не сервер

Tags: phpstorm, ide, ftp, settings

Возможно кто то поможет в вопросе.
Каким образом настроить php storm так что бы при сохранении изменений ftp документа он автоматов выгружался на сервер. Просмотрел массу ссылок на этот вопрос. выставлял настройки Upload changed и Warn when uploading - по разному, все равно тербует нажать на "Upload"

Возможно у меня бага какая то и нужно встяхнуть IDE или переустановить, возможно я где-то, что-то не то делаю.

Заранее благодарю за внимание.

[image: настройки ftp]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: скриншот]

Вот эти настройки важны. В принципе, можете перевести их на русский и будет понятнее :)
Выставьте как у меня на скрине

Comment: Благодарю. Мои мучения прекратились ) IDEшка классная, но количество настроек и пунктов иногда сводит с ума. Не на все удается найти быстрый ответ